Query a column with YYYYMMDD format to show current month value only?
I have a table1 like below, in the first column called "Calendar_Day", the format is YYYYMMDD



Calendar_Day
Plant
Stocks




20240316
ABC
100


20240511
DEF
850


20240508
GHI
520


20240105
JKL
222



I need to have the rows only for this current month (for example, it's in May 2024 now, so it only needs to show 202405XX, but next month, it should automatically show 202406XX only)



Calendar_Day
Plant
Stocks




20240511
DEF
850


20240508
GHI
520



How should I write the query in SQL?
select *
from table1
where ??????

Thank you!
I tried to use if, concenate but all result in error.

is Calendar_Day a string data type ? Why not using date data type ?

Why would you not store your dates using a proper date datatype?

Is the column of type date or something else? If it's not a date yet, are there only such values that can simply be converted to a date or also completely other values like Hello World which can't? Your goal should be to have a date column. Then you can just check if the date is part of the current month: ...calender_day BETWEEN DATETRUNC(MONTH, GETDATE()) AND EOMONTH(GETDATE()). Depending on the current data type and content of your column, it will be more or less easy to make it a date column.

Even if you can't or don't want to make this column a date column (let's say it must urgently also contain other strings or other numbers for whatever reason), you should add another column and store real dates there. You can in this case use TRY_CAST and update the new date column with the existing dates from the old column. Then make your date condition based on the new column, the old one will stay as it is.

Calendar_Day is a string data type, it's not date unfortunately, due to the upstream system

And what strings are possible in this column? Can they all be converted as date?

Storing the date as an INT in YYYYMMDD format is efficient (common in data warehouses) for large data sets that have to be sliced and diced based on dates, but you also need a Calendar table to join on, with the Calendar table's PK being the same INT in YYYYMMDD format. Then, you can join on the Calendar table, and in your WHERE clause define the filter, such as DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = CalendarTable.MonthPart AND DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) = CalendarTable.YearPart.

Reference: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho  If your date data is going to remain as INT in YYYYMMDD format, I'd recommend you generate a calendar table (i.e., Date Dimension) to use going forward. It'll make your life easier.

It is a straight forward query to check the current month and year and get the data from table1.
-- Assuming the current year and month as parts of the date
DECLARE @currentYearMonth CHAR(6) = CONVERT(CHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112)  -- YYYYMM format

Select @currentYearMonth as currentYearMonth




currentYearMonth




202405



SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE Calendar_Day like @currentYearMonth + '%';




Calendar_Day
Plant
Stocks




20240511
DEF
850


20240508
GHI
520




LEFT(Calendar_Day, 6) is not performant as it discourage the use of any index on Calendar_Day. Change to Calendar_Day like @currentYearMonth + '%'

Accept what @Squirrel says!

Your best solution (that would keep you out of trouble also in the future) is to change the column's type to date, or to add another column of type Date if you cannot change this column's type.
If you really have to stay with varchar then do not convert to date, that will only slow you down. In that case make your where clause based on varchar comparision, see examples below.
This answer is only to be used when you really need to keep varchar
select t.calendar_day,
       t.plant,
       t.stocks
from   table1 t
where  t.calendar_day like '202405%'

See dbFiddle here
This will also work if completely different and invalid data values are in that column as you can see in the dbFiddle link above
To make it work automatically from the current date, use this example
declare @value varchar(6) = convert(char(6), getdate(), 112)

select t.calendar_day,
       t.plant,
       t.stocks
from   table1 t
where  t.calendar_day like @value + '%'

See this corrected dbFiddle

if in next month, should I edit the code to "202406%'?? Then I need to update codes every month. that' why I need another way

@HiCarrie I edited my answer and showed you how to retrieve the year and month from the current date, is that what you need ?

It makes no sense they must "stick to varchar". Why should this be necessary? Even if the current column must stay as it is, they can create a new column of type date and run the date condition based on the new one.

@JonasMetzler I did wrote that they should change to column type varchar, my answer is for if the have to stay with varchar for some dark reason, I agree with you fully

This is basically the same as the other existing answer? What value do you provide over theirs?

@DaleK Actually you are right, I have just added some text to encourage to change the column's type to date, and the answer is only to be used if really need to stay with varchar

Well, in my opinion, all those existing answers should just be deleted, that's the wrong way and not necessary. OP should either make the current column a date column or create a new date column and store the dates there. This is much simpler, safer and faster. To me, it seems they just want a quick and dirty query based on varchar which is just incorrect and should not be done that way. The fact people write answers and explain how to do this incorrect way make the impression they should do it, even if they note in answers it is not recommended. If it's not recommended, just don't tell how.

@JonasMetzler They will found out how somehow anyway, if not on SO then somewhere else. But I see your point. You can always write your own answer and explain how to add a date column and use that for solving his problem

@JonasMetzler that's a bit harsh, we're not the best practice police, yes we should ensure that the best practice is made clear to the OP but in the end it up to them which solution they choose.

yes, of course we can set this to date type, thank you for guiding me how to do that. :)

is declare XXX a sql query? it still shows error when executing in databricks

@HiCarrie check the documentation.

Most oftenly you want to avoid using the "LIKE" operator at all times in SQL.
Therefore I'd suggest this solution instead.
Obviously, if the column is a numeric type. You should declare the variables as such as well..
DECLARE
  @MonthStart varchar(8) = FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyyMM') + '01'
, @MonthEnd   varchar(8) = FORMAT(GetDate(), 'yyyyMM') + '31'

SELECT 
    FORMAT(t.calendar_day, 'yyyyMM') + 'XX' as xxDay
  , *
FROM table1
WHERE Calendar_Day BETWEEN @MonthStart AND @MonthEnd


You know that format is terrible for performance? And I would avoid between also. And you also known that it is a varchar column, not a date, not an int, right?

about between

about format

Try this, it's simple and work
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    DATEPART(YEAR, calendar_day) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) 
    AND 
    DATEPART(MONTH, calendar_day) = DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE());

https://dbfiddle.uk/LWJhl0d3
this will only work if you create a column "calendar_day" with type DATE. May be a bad option for big data
OR
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    table1
WHERE 
    YEAR(calendar_day) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
    AND 
    MONTH(calendar_day) = MONTH(GETDATE());

https://dbfiddle.uk/IgEqTsML
it doesn't use DATEPART and works if the column "calendar_day" is of type varchar

And it implicitly coverts the string to a datetime which will probably perform worse than a straight string conpare

@MaximMazunin Use one of the plenty fiddle sites and try out your solution before answering a question, for example here: https://dbfiddle.uk/ER_9PaV-

oh, it doens't work from my side

It doesn't work because your column is not of type date. And it's generally a quite slow approach because it executes multiple functions for every row. Will likely be very inperformant.

I think the problem is the wrong data type for the 'calendar_day' column, I checked everything works

OP clarified that their data is in fact varchar. Your answer works by an implicit conversaion, but that may not work depending on regional settings.

@MaximMazunin You should note it's generally not recommended to execute functions in the WHERE clause which will run for every single row. Imagine a table can hold millions of rows, this can easily slow down your query, especially when other tables are joined. Get rid of this DATEPART for each row.

are YEAR and MONTH not also functions ? And don't you do a conversion from varchar to date in the background now ?

This will also fail if there are values in that column that cannot be converted to date, see this example

Why would a column of type date be a bad option for big data ?

The Estimated Number of Rows to be Read: is  736  (see this DBFIDFLE), and in that temp-table there are only 736 rows (in total) and only 2 records for the month of May in 2024.
